# Set dynamic aria-label in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to set a dynamic aria-label field for my `<div>` in AngularJS project.

In >= Angular 2.0 we have [attr.aria-label]="{{data}}"

How can I set a dynamic value for aria-label in AngularJS?

Comment: doesn't work in AngularJS. I tried to make it aria-label="{{data}}" and it works but not stable

Comment: aria-label="{{data}}" should work - what unstable with it?

Comment: it should but acts weird - from time to time aria-label value is blank (I checked that the {{data}} is defined and holds the data every time)